# Sharing a list between controllers safely in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, .net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1. I'm writing a controller to handle webhooks, and it's possible that the system sending the requests could send the same request multiple times. Each request has a notification ID header that will be the same for duplicate requests, so it's easy to filter them out.

What's the best way to handle this in ASP.NET Core that's properly thread-safe? Right now I'm storing a `List<string>` in `MemoryCache`, and it works, but I'm worried about thread safety. I don't know of a thread-safe list-like collection that offers something like `.Contains()` to quickly check if something exists in the collection.

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Would ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> with notification ID as a key work for you?

Comment: This approach does not scale, but collection you are looking for is ConcurentDictionary

Comment: @PavelShastov Would I need to do anything special with `MemoryCache` though?

Comment: No, MemoryCache is a thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using just [Asp.Net Core IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Without a collection object.

This way you'll get some control over cached objects lifetime. For example, you could keep it for one hour only.

```
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

    public ActionResult Get(string notificationId)
    {
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(notificationId, out _))
            return Ok();

        // Do stuff

        // Store key for one hour
        _cache.Set(notificationId, notificationId, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Warning!**

This approach makes sense if you have only one instance of the webhook and you are not going to horizontally scale it.

Or if you are okay with each instance having its own cache and potentially handling the same request one time per each instance.

Otherwise, a [distributed caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is required.